# GridView1.Attributes.Remove("DeleteRecord")

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, attributes

what is meaning of this code:

```
GridView1.Attributes.Remove("DeleteRecord");
```

or

```
GridView1.Attributes.Remove("onrowcommand");
```

or

```
GridView1.Attributes.Remove("UpdateRecord");
```

In other words, I want to disable insert, edit and delete method of a gridview in runtime and come to this code but it does not react.
do you have any other offer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the attributes property is for setting additional properties not methods. you are using it very incorrectly.

if you don't want the rowcommand to execute, remove the rowcommand="xxxx" from the aspx.

if you mean to keep the rowcommand, then in your rowcommand method (xxxx) in my example, write some c# code to intercept and not execute further in that method.

Comment: mson, Thank you. As you said I can write code c# code to avoid executing methods, but I was looking for a more easy way.

Comment: it's trivial code... if it's not trivial to you, you should practice anyway.

Comment: Ok, trivial or not trivial, is there any easy way or not? that the matter, if you know...